# Angular JS Handle controller Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events

I have an application having a lot of things to save in cascade, imaging a normal master - detail view.

In this view I have a "Save All" Button that save each row in an iteration, triggering jQuery custom events, to serialize the saving operations and prevent the generation an uncontrolled queue of requests.

Each time a row is saved, the program decrement the counter and launch the save of the new row.

Everything ends when there where no rows to save (counter = 0).

This is a code snippet doing this:

```
var save_counter = -1;

// Creates a counter and save content header when finished to save rows.
var updCounter = function(evt){

    // Update Counter
    save_counter--;
        
    // Register updates When there are not rows to skip
    if ((save_counter===0) 
        || (save_counter===0 && edit_status == "modified") ){

        console.log('Persist Master');
        $(document).trigger('save_ok');

    }
};    

saveRows = $(form_sel);

// Reset Save Counter
save_counter = saveRows.length;

// Iterate through lines
saveRows.each(function(idx){
    var form = $(this);

    // Execute Uptade Counter once
    form.one(update_counter, updCounter);

    // Per each performed save, decrese save counter
    form.trigger('submit');
});
```

Now I'm migrating some critical application modules, using angular but I have no idea to do that.

There is a best practice to perform a batch request call?

Is it a good idea to use `$scope` variables and `$watch`, using something like this?

```
var RowController = angular.controller('RowController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.rows = [
          {id : 1, title : 'lorem ipsum'}
        , {id : 2, title : 'dolor sit amet'}
        , {id : 3, title : 'consectetuer adipiscing elit'}
    ];

    // Counter Index
    $scope.save_counter = -1;

    // "Trigger" the row saving, changing the counter value
    $scope.saveAll = function () {
        $scope.save_counter = 0;
    };
    
    // Watch the counter and perform the saving
    $scope.$watch('save_counter', function(

        // Save the current index row
        if ($scope.save_counter >= 0 
                && $scope.save_counter < $scope.rows.length) {

            $http({
                url : '/row/' + $scope.rows[$scope.save_counter].id, 
                data: $scope.rows[$scope.save_counter]
            }).success(function(data){
                
                // Update the counter ...
                $scope.save_counter ++;

            }).error(function(err){

                // ... even on error
                $scope.save_counter ++;
            });

        };

    ));
});
```

Comment: Added `'` after `RowController` assuming a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) with promises ([$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)).

Here's an example:

```
app.factory('RowService', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    saveRow: function(row) {
      return $http({
        url: '/row/' + row.id,
        data: row
      });
    },

    saveAll: function(rows) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var firstRow = rows.shift();
      var self = this;

      // prepare all the saveRow() calls
      var calls = [];
      angular.forEach(rows, function(row) {
        calls.push(function() {
          return self.saveRow(row);
        });
      });

      // setup the saveRow() calls sequence
      var result = this.saveRow(firstRow);
      angular.forEach(calls, function(call) {
        result = result.then(call);
      });

      // when everything has finished
      result.then(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      }, function() {
        deferred.reject();
      })

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

And on your controller:

```
app.controller('RowController', function($scope, RowService) {
  ...

  $scope.saveAll = function() {
    // $scope.rows.slice(0) is to make a copy of the array
    RowService.saveAll($scope.rows.slice(0)).then(
      function() {
        // success
      },
      function() {
        // error
      })
  };
});
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BsHTCKvmeKTg7NRixF35?p=preview) for an example.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!
Just one another, this success / error calls are intended as globally? 
RowService.saveAll($scope.rows.slice(0)).then(
      function() {
        // success
      },
      function() {
        // error
      })

The row specific ajax error / success are handled in saveRow function right?

Comment: You can use them globally. If one of the `$http` requests fails, the error will be propagated to the callbacks defined in the _RowController_.

Comment: I didn't understand the way to defer request calls, using timeout. I changed a little bit on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OPsiQ187FeOjcoKpBJwT, I hope to be useful.

Comment: The timeout was just for demonstration, you should not use it. The `$http` service already returns a promise, so there's no need to need to defer it manually: `saveRow: function(row) { return $http.post(/* parameters */); }`.